# Ошибка: cout: необъявленный идентификатор

Tags: c++

Я только начал разбираться с плюсами. И тут же воткнулся в какой-то непонятный для меня косяк.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
}
```

Вроде все верно... Но при компиляции ошибка:

> ```
> cout: необъявленный идентификатор
> ```

Я почитал у вас тут похожие темы. Пишут, что область имен надо объявить, она есть. Вроде вообще все как надо. Я использую *VS 2017* для написания кода. Объясните, пожалуйста, что не так.

Answer (score 11):

Вот это

```
#include <iostream>
```

вы, вероятно, добавили сами перед

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

Поменяйте их местами. `stdafx.h` - это такой оченно хитрый вспомогательный заголовочный файл (который я бы, честно говоря, вообще не использовал :) - но вы уже сделали проект с использованием предварительно скомпилированного заголовка...) Пусть себе идет первым...

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо) Все работает!

Comment: Ну, если помогло - помечайте ответ как принятый :)

Answer (score -1):

попробуйте так

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

   cout << "Hello World ";
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
std::cout<<"Hello World";
```